# Horizontally mirrrored user name in comment

Tags: bug, comments, unicode

Have a look at this question please:

[I'm getting Chinese Text when using Windows 10 pipes in Delphi. How do I make it in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603940/im-getting-chinese-text-when-using-windows-10-pipes-in-delphi-how-do-i-make-it)

You can find there this display glitch:

[image]

It looks like Unicode handling bug. Is it known?

Browser info Chrome 79.0.3945.88

<sub>Before submitting I have:

- checked both links point to the same account

- tried finding similar reports using (mirrored/flipped/backwards) keywords</sub>

Comment: He's copy/pasting Unicode garbage, it probably included U+200F.  So feature, not a bug.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't that still be a bug in that it extends beyond the text of the comment?